# wrapping a custom hash table using swig

Tags: python, c, perl, hashtable, swig

I have a custom implementation of a hash table written in C for an application that I am developing. Now I want to create a wrapper for it in swig so that I can map them into native types like "dict" in Python. I want to be able to write a single interface file which I can use for both Perl and Python. First of all I want to know if this is even possible, or should I do it individually for each Python and Perl?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with one implementation file.  Depending on the complexity of your implementation, it can be as simple as:

```
%module my_hash

%inline %{
#include "my_hash.h"
%}
```

And generating the interface code with:

```
swig -python my_hash.i
swig -perl my_hash.i
```

If you have to write any custom typemaps, you may have to use `#ifdef SWIGPYTHON` or `#ifdef SWIGPERL` to specify language-specific code in the interface definition.